# Why the Ubuntu App Developer website is not showing content about development for desktop?

Tags: application-development

Looks like they removed every content that is not related with development for desktop. For example when you click in "Get Started" tab there is only information about the Ubuntu Touch and its SDK, when you click on "Resources" tab and then on "Programming languages" you only see C++, JavaScript and QML (no Python, Java, Mono, etc). You also can't find any information about Quickly, try clicking on "Quicky" at "Resources" in the website bottom and you will see a "Page not found" error.

Is the site under maintenance or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of the process of making Ubuntu a truly convergent platform, where the apps that you develop can run on any device or form factor, we've started the process of focusing the content on the App developer site to be about the [Ubuntu SDK](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/).

While Quickly will still be available and open to community participation and maintenance, **the recommended way to develop apps for Ubuntu is the Ubuntu SDK**.

This has been discussed at the last two virtual UDSs and you can track the progress and provide feedback on this [blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/appdev-1305-developer-site-gomobile)

Comment: It means that in the future most of the applications available for Ubuntu will use the QML? So the usage of GTK+ 3 in the development of new Ubuntu applications is discouraged?

Comment: The new click packages can only have dependencies on the Ubuntu SDK. Anything else will need be to bundled inside your packages. If you use GTK+ that will include the entire GTK+ stack. You will have a complete copy of GTK+ per GTK+ application. Can anyone say bloat?

Comment: So... you want us to stop using traditional tools and start using the Ubuntu SDK even though the SDK only supports Ubuntu Touch right now? Wow....

Comment: @Seth no body is asking you to stop using traditional tools. If you are serious about application development, then you choose your platform target and develop the app for that (this is true for Windows, Mac, iOS, Android) and use their SDK. If you need to create a multiplaform compatible application then the traditional tools you refer to (GTK?) are NOT the way to go !.

Comment: @SalihEmin I don't think you understand. The SDK only supports Ubuntu Touch ATM.

Comment: @Seth, no one is asking you to stop using traditional tools. However, as Salih Emin is mentioning, if you want to write applications for Ubuntu that run across multiple form factors and devices, the choice will be the SDK with QML, as there is currently no other technology that allows for this functionality.

Comment: Except for the fact that the SDK only supports Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: @DavidPlanella please help with this, I am literally out of options: How do I create C++ with QML or HTML with C++ apps which can be published to the Ubuntu store? I've searched everywhere with no help. The Ubuntu site for devs is almost useless and there is only half a page worth of content on "Publishing apps" and it only works for HTML and Javascript apps which have no real use on desktops. Unless there are huge chunks of API's and documentation you're not showing us.