# Are Python apps allowed in Ubuntu App Showdown?

Tags: application-development, python, qml, ubuntu-sdk

I want to know if python apps (containing only a .py file) are allowed in the latest app showdown.
If not, how can it be ported to QML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [rules](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/rules/) say:

- **Ubuntu SDK**: submissions must use some aspect of the Ubuntu SDK. They can be written in C++, QML, HTML 5 or OpenGL, as long as they use the SDK and it’s components where appropriate.

So the question is: does the Ubuntu SDK offer Python? And an answer has [already been provided](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314329/is-it-possible-to-use-python-with-the-ubuntu-sdk): no, sorry.

By the way, note that the first showdown required participants to make use of Quickly. That requirement [was dropped](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/06/ubuntu-app-showdown-no-longer-requires-quickly/) after requests from some of the participants.

Comment: Is there any way to port a python project to QML?

Comment: @apandada1: sorry, you are asking the wrong person. I have never had the pleasure to work with Qt and QML so far.