# Ubuntu 13.10 application using pyqt5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, pyqt

Is it possible to make Ubuntu application which will be fully functional in Ubuntu mobile using pyQT5.  However I know  that it s possible to make Ubuntu application using QT; what I'm confused about is using pyqt.

If so can you please provide me link to tutorial from where I can learn it. I have 5 years of experience in PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/a/314617/169250

Comment: I have used python in ubuntu, Gabriel, my question is totally different

Comment: Are you sure it's different? That question is about using Ubuntu SDK with python. Your question is about programming in python for Ubuntu Mobile. Ubuntu SDK is the officially recommended way to develop for Ubuntu, including touch. In my understanding, it's very close related. What did I miss?