# Will I be able to develop apps for ubuntu touch with python?

Tags: application-development, python, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I want to learn to develop apps for ubuntu touch, and I want to do that with python. So far SDK doesn't seem to support it. Will it support python in the future? Can I start developing apps with something like pyqt now?
If yes - can you give me some pointers about where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Is it possible to use Python with the Ubuntu SDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314329/is-it-possible-to-use-python-with-the-ubuntu-sdk) I don't think that the current status is different:

> pyqt might not be the best choice in terms of licensing commercial
>   applications

And taken from the ubuntu-phone mailing list [archive](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg04725.html):

> While PyOtherSide may work, it's not a supported language or platform
>   for the Ubuntu SDK, so we can't guarantee that it will always work or
>   work properly.  I would encourage you to use Javascript instead of at
>   all possible.